# JBoss 7 add jar to classpath

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy WAR file into JBoss 7.
I placed the WAR file in the standalone/deployments folder.
while starting the server I’m getting  ClassNotFoundError.
I believe Since the jars are not part of the WAR file and not placed in the WEB_INF/lib folder so I need to add them externally.

I read so many tutorials but I just can’t understand how it works.

So my question is how I simply add JAR files to the JBoss classpath.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add any jars that are not part of WebApp but are still needed to be loaded, one approach would trying to copy the jars at following location:
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext.

The JBOSS server should point to this java installation and this might resolve your issue.

This might be one way.

JBOSS 7 uses module based loading, hence most of the jars will be loaded if module is  included in standalone.xml.

You will need to check in JBoss Release notes if third party modules  can be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it by creating new module and by adding the module dependency in the MANIFEST of my jar.

Comment: You can also use a jboss-deployment-structure.xml to add a dependency on that custom module in your top-level deployment artifact.